# What happens if one end of an "ideal string" is vibrated at a frequency not equal to the harmonic modes?

Tags: waves, frequency, resonance

Let's say we have a string of length $L$ for which the wave propagation speed is $c$. We consider vertical displacements $u(x, t)$ along the string on domain $x\in [0, L]$. The right end $x=L$ is fixed at zero amplitude. The left end $x=0$ is driven at some angular frequency $\omega$.

We are looking for the string displacement $u(x, t)$ along the string on domain $x\in [0, L]$ assuming uniform tension/density, small displacements, no stiffness, and no drag. This means we want to find solutions $u(x, t)$ satisfying the wave equation $\partial_{t}^{2}u = c^{2}\partial_{x}^{2}u$ and special boundary conditions $u(0, t) = A\sin\omega t$ and $u(L, t) = 0$.

Comment: Interesting question. *Am I correct in this analysis?* It would help if you included your own derivation leading to that conclusion.

Comment: That is the steady state part of the solution. In general there is also a transient solution, depending on the initial displacement and velocity along the whole length of the string. In real life the transient solution dies away because of damping effects.

Comment: It'd be nice if someone could provide a full solution to the wave equation in this case. aleph?

Comment: @Gert I haven't done more reasoning than what I've written, but, yes, it does seem a bit of a stretch for me to say this is an "analysis." I'm hoping someone can help me flesh out the derivation to the correct answer.

Comment: @alephzero This is a very helpful note. I forgot all about the transient solutions. This question was inspired by a video showing a demo and I was very confused why it didn't show standing waves in one part. Your comment gave an answer why.

Comment: I might give this derivation a shot tomorrow. Don't wait up for it though, I'll ping if done. Ta.

Comment: Our cousins in Math.se have formulated an answer for the wave equation with Dirichlet BC: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246784/wave-equation-with-one-non-homogeneous-boundary-condition . It does seem lengthy so I'm not sure it's worth transcribing it here?

Comment: I think in addition to the forcing function, you would need to specify the initial conditions (displacement and transverse velocity at time zero as a function of x)

Comment: Also the intial phase of the forcing function would need to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

### Intro

When solving the 1D wave equation $\partial_{t}^{2}u = c^{2}\partial_{x}^{2}u$ on a finite interval $[0, L]$, a unique solution is fixed by having *two boundary conditions* and *two initial conditions*. The OP provided two boundary conditions and left the initial conditions undetermined, so it follows that the problem is underdetermined.

However, given two solutions $u_{1}, u_{2}$ that satisfy $u(0, t) = \phi(t)$ and $u(L, t) = 0$ for some fixed function $\phi(t)$, the difference $u_{1}-u_{2}$ is a solution to the wave equation with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions ($u(0, t) = 0$ and $u(L, t) = 0$). Thus, all solutions will be of the form $u = u_{1} + u_{0}$ where $u_{0}$ solves the problem with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions and $u_{1}$ is a particular solution to our problem. *We will simply look for at least a single solution $u_{1}$.* If the initial conditions are later provided, then $u_{0}$ and hence the solution $u = u_{1} + u_{0}$ for the given initial conditions is easily determined.

I will also say [a similar problem has been posed on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246784), but the boundary conditions are not the same (the right end has a Neumann BC instead of a Dirichlet BC), so not all methods (like taking $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+\phi(t)$) explained there are necessarily applicable here.

I've thought of a peculiar way to derive the solutions to this problem that I haven't seen elsewhere so I thought I'd share my method (Method 1) and then present solutions. There are probably better, easier, more generalizable methods than the one I am presenting here. If anyone has other methods, they are welcome to post.

---

### Method 1

This is the idiosyncratic method I found. Since our PDE is linear, it suffices to take the real or imaginary part of everything at the end.

Suppose a solution $u$ exists.
By using the change of coordinates $\xi = x-ct$ and $\eta = x+ct$ and applying the chain rule, we find our solution satisfies $\partial_{\xi}\partial_{\eta}u = 0$. This implies $u = f(\xi) + g(\eta) = f(x-ct) + g(x+ct)$. The boundary conditions imply
\begin{align*}
 u(0, t) &= f(-ct) + g(ct) &&= e^{i\omega t}, \\
 u(L, t) &= f(L-ct) + g(L+ct) &&= 0.
\end{align*}
The second equation, under the substitution $t\rightarrow t-L/c$, gives us the relation $f(2L-ct) = -g(ct)$. Substitution into the first equation gives $f(-ct) - f(2L-ct) = e^{i\omega t}$. Now we have a functional equation for $f$ that we want to solve.

To unclutter the functional equation, we define $\widetilde{f}(s) = -f(2Ls)$, use the variable $s = ct/(2L)$, and use $\Omega = 2\omega L/c$ so that our equation reduces to $\widetilde{f}(s+1) - \widetilde{f}(s) = e^{-i\Omega s}$.
To recap, we have
\begin{align*}
 g(x) = -f(2L-x),\; \widetilde{f}(s) = -f(2Ls), \,\text{ and }\, \widetilde{f}(s+1)-\widetilde{f}(s) = e^{-i\Omega s}
\end{align*}

To solve the functional equation for $\widetilde{f}$, we propose
\begin{align*}
 \widetilde{f}(s) = e^{-i\Omega s}s
\end{align*}
if $\Omega = 2\pi n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and
\begin{align*}
 \widetilde{f}(s) = \frac{e^{-i\Omega s} - 1}{e^{-i\Omega} - 1}
\end{align*}
otherwise.
Now that we have a form for $\widetilde{f}$, we can get the respective forms for $f, g$ and then we can obtain $u$ itself:

\begin{align*}
    u(x, t) &= f(x-ct) + g(x+ct) = f(x-ct) - f(2L-x-ct) = -\widetilde{f}(\tfrac{x-ct}{2L}) + \widetilde{f}(1 - \tfrac{x+ct}{2L})
\end{align*}

where $\Omega = 2\omega L/c$.

### Solution

Based on what we had in the previous section, after lots of algebraic manipulations and simplifying, we find that if $\omega = \pi n c/L$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then one possible solution is
$$ u(x, t) = e^{i\omega t}\left[ \cos\left(\frac{\omega x}{c}\right)\left( 1 - \frac{x}{L} \right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\omega x}{c}\right)\left( 1 - \frac{ct}{L} \right) \right]. $$
Otherwise, one possible solution is
\begin{align}\tag{1}
u(x, t) = e^{i\omega t}\frac{\sin\left( \frac{\omega(L-x)}{c} \right)}{\sin\left( \frac{\omega L}{c} \right)}. 
\end{align}

As explained above, the general solution is of the form $u = u_{1} + u_{0}$ where $u_{0}$ solves the problem with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions and $u_{1}$ is a particular solution to our problem such as the one given above.

If we are given initial conditions of the form $u(x, t=0) = f(x)$ and $\partial_{t}u(x, t=0) = g(x)$, then we may take the particular solution $u_{1}$ given above and define $u_{0} = u - u_{1}$. Our problem transforms into a case with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions $u_{0}(0, t) = u_{0}(L, t) = 0$ and initial conditions
$$ u_{0} = f(x)-u_{1}(x, 0) \quad\text{and}\quad \partial_{t}u_{0} = g(x)-\partial_{t}u_{1}(x, 0). $$

Note that our wave equation had no source terms or damping effects, so *this does not tell us what will be the steady-state solutions vs transient solutions in real life.*

(In real-life we can't vibrate one end of a string from $t=-\infty$ to $t=+\infty$ with no damping whatsoever and with other idealizations, so these expressions don't tell us much about what happens in the real-world. Doing a numerical simulation would be more fruitful at this point.)

---

### Method 2 - Separation of Variables

I wanted to also demonstrate how one could solve this by separation of variables. For more generality, we will consider the damped wave equation
$$ \partial^{2}_{t}u + k\partial_{t}u = c^{2}\partial^{2}_{x}u $$
with the same boundary conditions as before ($u(0, t) = \phi(t)$, $u(L, t) = 0$, and $\phi(t) = e^{i\omega t}$). Here the method will work only if $k\ne 0$ or $\omega \ne n\pi c/L$ (otherwise you run into issues).

We apply separation of variables by substituting the ansatz $u(x, t) = X(x)T(t)$.
This gives us the equation $XT'' + kXT' = c^{2}X''T$ which is equivalent to $1/c^{2}\cdot T''/T + k/c^{2}\cdot T'/T = X''/X$.
In the latter equation, the LHS is independent of $x$ and the RHS is independent of $t$, so both sides are equal to a constant, which we label as $-\lambda$.
This yields the equations
\begin{align}\tag{2}
 T'' + kT' + c^{2}\lambda T = 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad X'' + \lambda X = 0.
\end{align}

Now the boundary conditions dictate that $X(0)T(t) = e^{i\omega t}$ and $X(L) = 0$.
If we rearrange the first equation to be $X(0) = e^{i\omega t}/T(t)$ and let $C = X(0)$, we find that $T(t) = e^{i\omega t}/C$ (note that $C$ must be nonzero since $e^{i\omega t}$ is always nonzero).
The first equation of $(2)$ yields $-\omega^{2} + ik\omega + c^{2}\lambda = 0$, which is to say,
\begin{align}\tag{3}
 \lambda = \frac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}} - \frac{ik\omega}{c^{2}}.
\end{align}

When we plug $(3)$ into the second equation of $(2)$ and collect all conditions placed on $X$, we find
\begin{align}\tag{4}
 X'' + \left( \frac{\omega^{2} - ik\omega}{c^{2}} \right) X = 0, \qquad X(0) = C, \qquad X(L) = 0.
\end{align}
This is a second-order ODE boundary value problem.

Assuming $\omega\ne 0$ (which I will assume is the case from here and onwards), the ODE in $(4)$ has the general solution
$$ X = Ae^{i(\beta + i\gamma) x} + Be^{-i(\beta + i\gamma)x} $$
where
\begin{align*}
    \beta &= \frac{1}{c}\sqrt{\frac{\omega^{2} + \sqrt{\omega^{4} + \omega^{2}k^{2}}}{2}} \quad\text{and}\quad \gamma = -\frac{\text{sign}(\omega k)}{c}\sqrt{\frac{-\omega^{2} + \sqrt{\omega^{4} + \omega^{2}k^{2}}}{2}}.
\end{align*}
Matching boundary conditions yields the system
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 \\ e^{-\gamma L}e^{i\beta L} & e^{\gamma L}e^{-i\beta L}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
 C \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}. $$
The determinant of the above matrix is $D = e^{\gamma L}e^{-i\beta L} - e^{-\gamma L}e^{i\beta L}$.
As long as $\gamma\ne 0$ or as long as $\omega\ne n\pi c/L$, the determinant is guaranteed to be nonzero and the system has the unique solution
$$ A = \frac{Ce^{2\gamma L}}{e^{2\gamma L} - e^{2i\beta L}} \qquad\text{and}\qquad B = \frac{-Ce^{2i\beta L}}{e^{2\gamma L} - e^{2i\beta L}}. $$

Plugging this back to $X$ and taking $u = XT$ gives us a solution.

### Solution

When we go through Method 2, we obtain
$$ u(x, t) = e^{i\omega t}\frac{ e^{\gamma(2L-x)}e^{i\beta x} - e^{i\beta(2L-x)}e^{\gamma x} }{e^{2\gamma L} - e^{2i\beta L}} $$
as a solution. When we plug $k=0$, the solution $(1)$ found in Method 1 is obtained.